# Why am I getting a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: string, char

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++) 
{           
  char ans = s.next().charAt(i);    
}
```

I am getting a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Why it is happening?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-

Answer (score 1):

Because `s.next()` is returning a `String` with less than 5 characters.  Try printing out `s.next()` to see the value if you expected it to be longer.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the exception cause you are trying to assign a char in your "ans" variable which is not available. The reason behind this is, the string you're getting by calling the 's.next()' method is not returning a string with at least 5 characters. Let's say the string is "Me" and you're trying to loop through it 5 times where there is only two characters. So when you're trying to look for the 3rd indexed character there is none and so you're getting the "StringIndexOutOfBoundsException"......

Answer (score 0):

You can also re-use the Scanner object, there's no need to create a new one for each user input.
And: "charCount = charCount++;" --> "charCount++;"